# How do I compare a result from "findstr" with a fixed string?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, cmd, findstr

I want to extract the default gateway from "ipconfig" and compare it with a fixed string in an "if" statement in a batch file. Here's my code:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in (`ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"Default Gateway"`) do set gateway=%%c

if /i "%gateway%" == "10.0.12.254"
Echo Hello world!
```

The result is I get the following error message:
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%c in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /c:"Default Gateway"') do set gateway=%%c`

Comment: `if /i "%gateway%" == "10.0.12.254" Echo Hello world!`. You got one linebreak too much (which generates the syntax error)

Comment: Why suffer with batch? Use PowerShell. One-line command: `Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=TRUE" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DefaultIPGateway`

Comment: Just another option: `ipconfig |findstr /R /C:"Default Gateway .* 10.0.12.254">nul 2>&1 && echo found it`

Comment: Stephan's suggestion did the trick. I feel like an idiot! Thanks, guys!

Comment: @SamWilliam, it is not necessary to use the `usebackq` option in your code instance.  That is why I took it out and used the standard ticks (single quote).